# Scripts in flash files

Tags: firefox, flash-player

I use firefox, and sometimes videos that I watch in yotube executing very slowly then sometimes I get alert like this: "Some scripts in this video may make Adobe Flash player run slower, do you want to disable this scripts?". If I press yes, video stop executing totally and I see gray screen. I thing that in this videos would be some viruses, and so on, and generally it really make computer run very slow. Is there some way to disable scripts but not movie?

Answer (score 1):

(Posting this as an answer because there's more room)

Just because something makes the computer slow does not indicate that it is a virus. (In fact, most viruses nowadays don't show up at all, but that's a different question). YouTube uses scripts to load its videos, so no, it isn't possible to disable ActionScript. It would be similar to disabling Flash entirely. Have you tried, clearing your cache, clearing your cookies, or using a different browser? Does this affect other computers on the same network?

Comment: Thank you for response,I tried to watch this video (http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2a6HMqsYnxk) on different browser (Opera) but this is the same result. There is no issue with caches or cookies, this is specifically some scripts that make it slow. The question is, why there is only several videos with this bad script, and most of videos works fine?